# equation of a cylinder jacket

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry, geometric-construction

how would you calculate this?

A circular cylinder, height $14$, base radius $2$, has the axis of rotation!

[image]

What is the equation of the cylinder jacket when the center of the base circle is the origin? Enter a solution with the help of
rotation matrices and using quaternions.

I know that a cylinder equation is: $f(x,y,z)=0=x²+y²-5, 0 < z < 10$, but how do i use it in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without using quaternions.

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions for rotation matrix about an axis and an angle. The axis $\vec{u}$ in your case is $(2,1,2)$. You also need to normalize it. Say the angle is $\theta$.

You can then represent the original $(x,y,z)$ by the new $(x',y',z')$ using the rotation matrix. You should use $-\theta$ since you are doing it reversely. This should give you equation
$$x=f(x',y',z',\theta)\\y=g(x',y',z',\theta)\\z=h(x',y',z',\theta)$$

Then use the original equation
$$x^2+y^2=4, 0\leq z\leq 14$$

to find the new equations.

Comment: I guess this is the answer but i need to understand it so thank you very much i will work with this.